# PublishingPageLayout - force relative urls

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

Does anyone know if there is a way to change it so page layouts are stored in the page using a relative url
currently we have:

```
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">http://mydomain.com/sites/Psoriasis/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom_Layouts/PW_layout2.aspx, PW_layout2</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
```

and we want:

```
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">/_catalogs/masterpage/Custom_Layouts/PW_layout2.aspx, PW_layout2</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
```

this is so we can easily move the site to another web application via wsp at a later date

Comment: Try some of the solutions on this similar SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634449/relative-urls-in-sharepoint-master-page Note the accepted one seems to not be the **correct** one :)

Comment: problem is when you select a page layout for a page, it puts the absolute url into the page aspx file rather than relative - I know I could change it manually after, but that isn't ideal as new pages could be created all the time and then when the site is moved it wont work anymore